# C program skips getchar

Tags: c, struct, io, scanf, getchar

I'm playing with structs and I wrote this trivial program that asks user their name and gender and birth date. It all works fine except when I added name part (I added it after gender and birth date). It skips the gender part and goes straight to birth date. Now if you comment out the scanf for name, it all works fine.

Why is asking user's name causing problems?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Customer
{
  char name[20];
  char gender;
  int birthdate;
};

void INT()
{
  struct Customer *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Customer));
  puts("enter your name:");
  scanf("%s", who->name);
  puts("enter gender: M/F");
  who->gender = getchar();
  puts("and birth date:");
  scanf("%d", &who->birthdate);

  printf("You gender is %c and you were born in %d\n", who->gender, who->birthdate);

  free(who);
}

int main()
{
  INT();
  return 0;
}
```

My question was marked as a duplicate of [Execution skips getchar() in loop after carriage return and putchar()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621329/execution-skips-getchar-in-loop-after-carriage-return-and-putchar), but is not in any way similar to that one. Plus that one doesn't have any viable answer.

Comment: It's because `scanf` doesn't eat that `\n` you end your name with, so `getchar` grabs it from `stdin` and is all happy and returns immediately. If you comment out the first `scanf`, you don't type anything before execution ends, so `getchar` works properly. BTW This doesn't have much to do with C++ so that tag is incorrect.

Comment: Change `scanf("%s", who->name);` to `scanf("%s%*c", who->name);` to fix the problem

Comment: An erratum for my first comment, since I cannot edit it anymore: "before execution ends" should be "before execution gets there", of course.